# Can I use WebSockets for desktop applications?

Tags: c#, websocket

That's it. It's a newbie question, probably. I'm almost giving up on TcpClient/Listener because of NAT and firewall issues. I wanted to know if theres an alternative. port 80 probably doesn't have to deal with any of these annoying things. I hope the answer is Yes.

Comment: What do you use to write your desktop application? Winforms? WPF? Also you can choose the port you want with TcpClient and TcpListener

Comment: I use WPF. I know about the port. I didn't mention it because until now I didn't know you had the option NOT to choose a port. But I always thought it would be bad programming practice or it would simply fail if I chose the port reserved for the http protocol for sending raw binary data. Would it work? and would it solve my NAT and firewall problems?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Write a desktop server or client? The distinction is very important.

Comment: It could work, and it would be bad practice as you said. You should look at your network problem instead of looking for another library, because whatever library you'll use, the problem will remain the same. Can't you choose a port for your application and then authorize it in your firewall and add the appropriate settings in your router?

Comment: both. It's supposed to be a tic-tac-toe game, my first experience as a game programmer, and it's proving to be really frustrating. The idea is the following: One computer will host a client and a server. The client in this computer will connect to the server in this same computer. Another person's computer somewhere else over the internet will run a client, this client will connect to the remote server. The 2 clients intermediated by the server will then play the game

Comment: You'll never get this working easily if the clients are both peers. The normal approach would be to host a game server that is visible to both clients on the net. Most non-dev people don't have port 80 open on their routers.

Comment: @ppetrov yes, I could do that. But I'm trying to make something that would run on a lot of computers each would possibly have a different router model and a different firewall solution. I don't want people to be forced to manually make a port mapping in their router. I'd like a solution that would be easy and transparent to the user. UPnP didn't work.

Comment: You need a server that is visible to both clients over the web. You could host this yourself and set up router/firewall rules to make it visible over the net, but client being both server&client causes exactly the problems you are seeing. For something as lightweight as tictactoe, you might be able to leverage XMPP, but in all cases, the only **reliable** way is to have a server at a fixed network address visible to both clients.

Comment: @spender I see. I thought 80 and 443 were exceptions to the rule, and both the router and the firewall would allow inbound connection requests. Any good books on the subject I could buy then? I really want to learn how to code games.

Comment: I don't do books. Routers will (in almost all cases) allow any outgoing connection to any port. However, opening up ports for incoming connections is something that is (rightly) difficult to do. If this were me, I'd use XMPP (Jabber) and a public XMPP server for comms. https://list.jabber.at/

Comment: http://primaryobjects.com/CMS/Article130.aspx or someone's similar project: https://github.com/micahlmartin/RPS-Xmpp

Comment: @spender That's really interesting! I'll look into that. Although messages based on XML may not be suitable for more complex and performance demanding games (which are my future goal), this thing has a lot of potential in a lot of other areas.

Comment: @user2212990 as spender said, you need a separate server application that you can host on your computer, and open the right ports to inbound connections, that way you only have to configure your router, and the clients won't have anything to do but connect to your server

Comment: @ppetrov I was thinking more of a game that anyone could easily host without even having to think about their routers. I was hoping for a programatic solution for the port forwarding. The funny thing is, it exists, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

What about the [SignalR](http://signalr.net/)  over WebScockets

Comment: I've never heard of it, but after a fast googling, I think that's an open source third-part library/project right? And can I use that for desktop applications? And would it solve all my NAT and firewall problems?

Comment: We don't know what your "NAT and firewall problems" are.

Comment: @spender well, port mapping using UPnP isn't an exact science, apparently. Some routers return null when you ask for their static mappings collection so you can add your own, even when they have UPnP enabled, they just don't have the action. About the firewall, some of them, like my McAfee silently blocks the client from connecting to the TcpListener, without even asking (I have to check the firewall history to know the connection was blocked). I know there's a way to add rules to Windows Firewall through code, but I wanted a more general solution

Comment: I have UPNP turned off because I don't like apps opening up ports that I don't know about. I'm not alone.

Comment: That's probably true, but that wasn't the case with this specific test when a router returned it's static port mapping collection as a null. UPnP was certainly on. I used a software to explore the UPnP actions the router had, and it didn't had the one necessary to add a port mapping programatically

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can implement WebSockets in a non-browser application, but it won't solve your problem.

When you try to open a server listening to websocket connections, you will run into the same problem you ran into when you created a normal socket connection: Personal firewall solutions will get in the way and not every router will forward the port you've chosen. Using the well-known port 80 won't help you here. It is quite uncommon for normal consumers to have a webserver running behind their NAT router, so by default no NAT router will forward the port unless specifically configured to do so.

A NAT router will generally prevent any hosts behind it to act as servers unless configured to allow it. When you want the users to not worry about their NAT configuration, both users must act as clients. The only way to do this is by having a central server all players connect to.

While hosting a server is still not free, it has become quite cheap due to cloud-based hosters who will rent you small, virtualized servers for very modest prices. The smallest instance from [Amazon EC2](http://aws.amazon.com/de/ec2/pricing/) only costs you 2 cents per hour or $14.40 per month. Or you can build your own server from some spare-parts and host it on your own internet connection. When you don't have a static IP address you can use a dynamic nameserver service like [no-ip](http://freedns.no-ip.com/) or [DynDNS](http://dyn.com/dns/).

Comment: I would like to implement the solution you are talking about let's say I configured a webserver with dyndns or no-ip, how can I connect clients to each other, is there a way that they connect using websocket directly without going through the server ?

Comment: @MehdiKaramosly I think I explained clearly enough why you need a central server. When you have several clients connected to your server and want them to communicate with each other, you just have to listen to their messages and forward them to the right other connection.

Comment: thanks for the info, however what I wanted to know is, is it possible to initiate the connection by the server and then the two peers will connect directly without going through the server and it seems that is not possible. thx

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, but please don't.
I would suggest to change your architecture:

Use a server socket as a main point to handle clients. This server has to have a visible IP/port. In this case you may have clients behind nuts, and do not bother.